# Scale a column of SparseVectors without UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with a feature column of SparseVector. I need to scale each *row* by a scalar. I have a working implementation below that employs a UDF. The following depicts the original and scaled feature columns:

```
+-------------------+-------+-------------------+
|           features|weights|     scaledFeatures|
+-------------------+-------+-------------------+
|(6,[0,1],[0.5,1.0])|    1.0|(6,[0,1],[0.5,1.0])|
|(6,[2,3],[1.5,2.0])|    2.0|(6,[2,3],[3.0,4.0])|
|(6,[4,5],[0.5,1.0])|    3.0|(6,[4,5],[1.5,3.0])|
+-------------------+-------+-------------------+
```

Is there a way to do this using Spark's native, and optimized, methods instead of a UDF?

Similarly, is there a Spark-native way to scale a SparseVector by a scalar? See the line below the "Scale the SparseVector" comment in the UDF defined below.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}

// Scaling a SparseVector column
val data = Array(
  (new SparseVector(6, Array(0,1), Array(0.5, 1.0)), 1.0),
  (new SparseVector(6, Array(2,3), Array(1.5, 2.0)), 2.0),
  (new SparseVector(6, Array(4,5), Array(0.5, 1.0)), 3.0)
)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF("features", "weights")

val scaleUDF = udf((sv: SparseVector, w: Double) => {
  // Scale the SparseVector
  val unzipped = sv.indices.zip(sv.values).map(iv => (iv._1, iv._2*w)).unzip
  new SparseVector(sv.size, unzipped._1, unzipped._2)
})

val scaledDF = df.withColumn("scaledFeatures", scaleUDF(col("features"), col("weights")))
scaledDF.show()
+-------------------+-------+-------------------+
|           features|weights|     scaledFeatures|
+-------------------+-------+-------------------+
|(6,[0,1],[0.5,1.0])|    1.0|(6,[0,1],[0.5,1.0])|
|(6,[2,3],[1.5,2.0])|    2.0|(6,[2,3],[3.0,4.0])|
|(6,[4,5],[0.5,1.0])|    3.0|(6,[4,5],[1.5,3.0])|
+-------------------+-------+-------------------+
```

Comment: `Vector` (including `SparseVector`) is not a native SQL object and cannot be processed directly. Even built-in ML tools normally  use `udfs`. You might find some serde hacks that could omit explicit `Vector` object, but I would much more expensive to apply one than to use `udf`. In other words - there is no such option.

Comment: I wonder if there is any serious performance implications for my approach vs a UDF that converts everything to Breeze types for the operations, which seems to be the most common approach I've seen on SO